# $G$ is Abelian if and only if $[e,e]$ is the only commutator of $G$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, derived-subgroup

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) claims that for a given group $G$ with the identity element $e$ the commutator $[e,e]=e$ is the only commutator if and only if $G$ is Abelian.

I know that for a given $N \trianglelefteq G$ the quotient $G/N$ is Abelian if and only if $[G,G] \le N$ and this shows that the commutator subgroup of $G$ is the minimal normal subgroup for which $G/N$ is Abelian.

But does this help to prove that "$G$ is Abelian if and only if $[e,e]$ is the only commutator of $G$"?

If yes then how?

Also does there exist any name for $[e,e]$?

Comment: By definition of the group $[G,G]$ the title claim follows directly. To be generated by commutators $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ simply reduces to be generated by $[e,e]=e$ if $G$ is abelian. Indeed, $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=xx^{-1}yy^{-1}=e$. The converse goes similarly.

Comment: But of course you are right, it also follows from [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847005/the-commutator-subgroup-k-of-g-is-the-smallest-subgroup-such-that-g-k-is?rq=1), which you have explained. Why? Because $K=\{e\}$ obviously is the smallest subgroup such that $G/K$ is abelian if $G$ is abelian.

Comment: The point is that this result is very easy, and you can prove it directly from the definition of $[G,G]$. You don't need to use the result about when $G/N$ is abelian.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia claims that the identity element $e$ is the only commutator iff $G$ is Abelian.

$[e,e]=e$ always holds, and yes it has a name: the identity element.

The claim is immediate from the fact that $[a,b]=e\iff ab=ba$, which is clear by the definition of commutator: $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$.

Comment: Dear 45465, the converse is really just as I said in my comment - mathematicians would say "trivial". But why not ask a "trivial" thing (although I believe you could find out it yourself and that would be better than asking other people).