# Determine the commutator of the non-abelian group of order $pq$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

By the Sylow theorem, I know that there exists normal subgroup of order $p$. But the commutator is the smallest normal subgroup $G'$ such that $G/G'$ is abelian, so it suffices to show that Sylow $q$-subgroup is not normal. But how can I see this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847005/the-commutator-subgroup-k-of-g-is-the-smallest-subgroup-such-that-g-k-is

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood the notion of "smallest." It means Sylow $q$-subgroup must contain commutator.

Comment: If both Sylows are normal, then the group is abelian.

Comment: @Arturo Is there a theorem for that? How can I show it?

Comment: If $N,M\triangleleft G$ and $N\cap M=\{e\}$, then for every $x\in N$ and $y\in M$, you have $xy=yx$ (because $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy\in N\cap M$). So if $P$ is the $p$-Sylow, which is abelian, and $Q$ is the $q$-Sylow, which is abelian, both normal, then $P\cap Q=\{e\}$, and $G=PQ$ just by size considerations, so $G$ is necessarily abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is the case that the Sylow $p$-subgroup cannot be normal (I’m assuming that $p\lt q$, though you never say so), you don’t need that.

Recall that if $G$ is any group, and $N$ is any normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is abelian, then $G’\leq N$. Thus, if the $q$-Sylow subgroup $Q$ of $G$ is normal, then $G/Q$ is of order $p$ and hence abelian, so we *know* that $G’\leq Q$. As $Q$ is of prime order, this means either $G’$ is trivial of $G’=Q$. But $G$ itself is nonabelian by assumption, so you know that $G’$ cannot be trivial. Thus, $G’=Q$.